# C++ can memory leak lead to memory error?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

"Memory error" in the title means the type of error that can cause the program to crash or corrupt managed memory.

To make it clearer, also assume memory full is not this type of "memory error".

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your leak causes you to run out of memory then one thing that can happen is that memory allocations will fail. If you are not correctly dealing with these failed allocations then all sorts of bad things can happen

But , in general, I would say that if you have memory corruption going on its not due directly to the leak. More likely the leak is irrelevant or the leak and the memory trashing are a symptom of a different bug

valgrind?

Answer (score 0):

If leak will be big enough, yes it will.

Comment: It would need to be a leak that makes the application run out of memory and then try to access through the failed pointer

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it does. memory allocation will just allocate memory and when you are out of memory it will allocate memory which is in use.

If you are able to simulate your program in a simulator you can just put your function in a infinite while loop and check your task manager. if the task of your simulation is going up to tens of MB's there is certainly a leak in your memory.

Comment: thats a pretty odd platform that will reallocate already allocated memory

Comment: I believe C++ does not have garbage collector so it won't reuse the allocated memory

Comment: and even if it had a GC the memory is not free (otherwise it would not be a leak) and so must not be reallocated

Comment: I agree with the other comments, if you have a big leak you might run out of memory.... and a memory allocation will fail. If this goes unchecked you might end up accessing through a null pointer... but this is an extreme case